# Accessing HTTPSession in a Camel route

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

Is it possible to access current HTTPSession inside camel route?
I want to access Username and Session-Id etc and pass it to some queue. 
Using Tomcat web server for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

If you have a Camel route with the servlet component, then you can access the HttpSession instance.

There is some details at this page: http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html, at the section *session support*. This example should apply to the servlet component as well.

And we have a servlet example here: http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-example.html
You can possible take a peak at.